# Javascript to find if string terminates in a forward slash

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

If I have a string loaded into a variable, what's the appropriate method to use to determine if the string ends in "/" forward slash?

```
var myString = jQuery("#myAnchorElement").attr("href");
```

Comment: jQuery cannot do that. However, JavaScript can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the last character of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884632/how-to-get-the-last-character-of-a-string)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A regex works, but if you want to avoid that whole cryptic syntax, here's something that should work: [javascript/jquery add trailing slash to url (if not present)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531363/javascript-jquery-add-trailing-slash-to-url-if-not-present)

```
var lastChar = url.substr(-1); // Selects the last character
if (lastChar !== '/') {         // If the last character is not a slash
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `regex` and do:

```
myString.match(/\/$/)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to just check the last character via:

```
var endsInForwardSlash = myString[myString.length - 1] === "/";
```

EDIT: Keep in mind, you would need to check that the string is not null first to keep from throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring and lastIndexOf:

```
var value = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JQuery for that.

```
function endsWith(s,c){
    if(typeof s === "undefined") return false;
    if(typeof c === "undefined") return false;

    if(c.length === 0) return true;
    if(s.length === 0) return false;
    return (s.slice(-1) === c);
}

endsWith('test','/'); //false
endsWith('test',''); // true
endsWith('test/','/'); //true
```

You can also write a prototype

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(pattern) {
    if(typeof pattern === "undefined") return false;
    if(pattern.length === 0) return true;
    if(this.length === 0) return false;
    return (this.slice(-1) === pattern);
};

"test/".endsWith('/'); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do that already natively with modern javascript:

```
mystring.endswith('/')
```

This feature has been introduced since ES2015 and works well in all browsers.